# Indentation after braces in C

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

I don't know what the formal name of it is (this being one of the reasons that I can't find how to achieve it). But, what I want is to make Emacs start the second bracket with the same amount of space that is used in the first one and when you press Enter to go in a new line, that line to start with the same amount of spaces if there is a bracket.

I am not looking for a weird customization (unless it is a last resort). I just am looking for a typical feature in most IDE, that I am sure you use if you write code in your Emacs.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(i<5)
    {

        /* I want by pressing Enter the cursor to start in here 
        so to write the print */
        print("Text")


    }
    /* I want this bracket to close automatically 
    under the first one (of the if) and not in the beginning. */

}
```

Comment: @Malabarba maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question appears to be dealing with two independent issues:

1. you want the <kbd>RET</kbd> character to automatically indent; and
2. you want an indentation style that is different from the Emacs default.

## Electric <kbd>RET</kbd>

A character that performs something else than just inserting itself is called *electric* in Emacs.  There are two ways in Emacs to make <kbd>RET</kbd> electric: the generic *electric-mode*, which you enable by doing `M-x electric-indent-mode`, and works in all modes; and the CC-mode specific minor mode *electric mode*, which you enable by typing `C-c C-l` in a CC-mode buffer.

Please try both, and choose whichever your prefer.

## Changing the style of indentation

Your preferred indentation style differs from Emacs' default in two ways: it uses 4 spaces indentation, while Emacs uses 2, and it puts curly braces beneath the control operators, rather than on the same line.

The former issue is easily solved:

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
```

The latter is hardly more involved:

```
(setq c-default-style (cons '(c-mode . "k&r") c-default-style)
```

You can change the used style for a single buffer by doing `M-x c-set-style`.  Please see the CC-Mode info manual for the available styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't see it as a two different things because anyone writing code sees it as one. The result you want is to be able to have code blocks created automatically, that means brackets aligned. I will check your answer and get back to you!

Answer (score 7):

[smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/), a solution for advanced handling of pairs (such as `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `<>`, ...) supports [pre- and post-action hooks](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Permissions#pre-and-post-action-hooks). With these it's possible to make Emacs indent the content of a `{}` pair after hitting `RET` after the beginning `{`, the `}` is inserted at the same time as the `{`. The following snippet is taken from the documentation and sets up the described behaviour for C++:

```
(sp-local-pair 'c++-mode "{" nil :post-handlers '((my-create-newline-and-enter-sexp "RET")))

(defun my-create-newline-and-enter-sexp (&rest _ignored)
  "Open a new brace or bracket expression, with relevant newlines and indent. "
  (newline)
  (indent-according-to-mode)
  (forward-line -1)
  (indent-according-to-mode))
```

Comment: I disabled `auto-pairs` and installed `smartparens` and it somehow broke the intended behavior in doing `{|}`. I was going to disable `smartparens` and go back to `auto-pair` before I found this answer. :)